# How long do coffee seeds require to germinate?

Tags: germination

I bought some seeds of coffee to grow a plant in my living-room.
I put them between a couple of paper towels and I wet them.
Then I covered them with a dish, so that light cannot affect them, and I keep them in my living-room, at about 20 °C.
After some days, I cannot see any improvement, yet (the seeds absorbed some water, but they haven't germinated, yet).

So, I wander how long should I wait, before giving up and throw them away...

(I checked [How do germinate the seed of a coffee plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/8871/7262), but it doesn't say anything about time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The potential for germination will continue for almost four months, but after this time the germination rate is several fold less and germination time is significantly longer.  Fresh seeds should germinate in 2.5 months, but old seeds can take as long as 6 months. Coffee in pergamino is even better. If this is available plant the coffee face down in the pergamino.
>
> It is advisable to pre-germinate the seeds.  First soak the coffee seeds in water for 24 hours.  Then sow the seeds in damp sand or wet vermiculite in which the excess water has been drained.  Otherwise, you can place the seeds between moist coffee sacks, which should be watered twice a day and drained well.

[Growing Coffee Beans at Home](http://www.coffeeresearch.org/coffee/homegrowing.htm)

So looks like it takes a long time to germinate a seed.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some experience here.

I grow my own coffee trees for fun (still working on a decent yield), but I have experimented with germination using freshly picked beans.
I still soak the beans after they're picked and the outer skin is removed, as this helps remove the slimy film around the bean/seed which makes it easier to germinate as the shell around the bean is more brittle that way.
I place the beans on wet cotton balls (paper towel works well too), and then into an air-tight container or bag to prevent moisture loss.  Place them in a warm position and wait :)
In my temperate climate, the first signs of roots popping out of the bean are after about 1 month (this varies bean to bean as well), once the root is about 1cm long, I'll put them into a good potting mix and keep them in the same warm, well-lit position.  The roots will take hold and the bean will start to rise into the air, it will take another month before you see the first leaves emerge from the bean.
After that, you're off and racing.

Comment: Does scarification speed things up?

Comment: I've never tried, but thanks for the tip, I'll give it a go on the next batch.